# How do I fix this code to recognise overlapping strings?

Tags: python, string, substring, overlapping

```
entrada = str(input().lower())

replace = "mem".lower()
find = entrada.lower()
count = 0
while (entrada.find(replace) != -1):
   entrada = entrada.replace(replace, "", 1)
   count +=1

print(count)
```

No count,list or lambda can be used.
I'm suposed to make a program that receives a lower string from the user then finds, counts and print the number of times a substring appeared.
But I'm having problems with overlapping strings.

example: string is memem, the expected exit is 2

Comment: First I'm not sure why you're casting to string after lower. if input is not string, lower will most likely throw an `AttributeError`. Also my question - the user provides both the substring and string?

Comment: Only string and it has to be lower

Comment: have you tried [my approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29850431/4637583) from your other thread?  oops, Sorry that wasn't you.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use the second argument of [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) which indicates an optional index to start searching for the substring within a string.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

> str.find(sub[, start[, end]])¶ Return the lowest index in the string
>   where substring sub is found, such that sub is contained in the slice
>   s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in
>   slice notation. Return -1 if sub is not found.

So if we keep track of the `last_index` found in a variable, we can simply start the search for the substring again in the next possible index. Expressed in code, this is the expression 
`last_index + 1`. If `last_index` is ever -1, we stop searching for the substring and output our count:

```
mystr = 'memem'
mysubstr = 'mem'
count = 0
last_index = -1
while True:
    last_index = mystr.find(mysubstr, last_index + 1)
    if last_index == -1:
        break
    count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
i = 0
while True:
    i = entrada.find(replace, i) + 1
    if i:
         count += 1
    else:
        break
```

This will then find `replace` in `entrada`, increment the count, find `replace` in `entrada[i+1:]` where `i` is the start of the previous match, increment the count, and repeat forever.